# PyMySQL not Inserting Data

Tags: python, mysql, syntax, pymysql

I have a piece of code which is taking Windows logs and inserting various pieces of information into an mySQL database. The code is running perfectly with no errors, but does not actually input the data into the table. The table remains blank. I pulled my mySQL syntax from an example with some modification, so I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong. I have a feeling it has either to do with the data types, or some changes I made to the syntax.

```
import sys
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import win32evtlog # requires pywin32 pre-installed
import win32evtlogutil 
import time


server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'System' # 'Application' # 'Security'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = 
win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)

while True:
for event in events:
    evt_tp = event.EventType
    if evt_tp != (1 or 2 or 8):
            eve_cat = str(('Event Category:', event.EventCategory))
            eve_timegen = str(('Time Generated:', event.TimeGenerated))
            eve_srcnm =  str(('Source Name:', event.SourceName))
            eve_id = str(('Event ID:', event.EventID))
            eve_typ =  str(('Event Type:', event.EventType))
            data = event.StringInserts
            if data:
                print ('Event Data:')
                for msg in data:
                    print(msg)

            print(type(eve_cat))
            print(type(eve_timegen))
            print(type(eve_srcnm))
            print(type(eve_id))
            print(type(eve_typ))
            print(type(data))
            time.sleep(10)

    else:
        eve_cat = ('Event Category:', event.EventCategory)
        eve_timegen = ('Time Generated:', event.TimeGenerated)
        eve_srcnm =  ('Source Name:', event.SourceName)
        eve_id = ('Event ID:', event.EventID)
        eve_typ =  ('Event Type:', event.EventType)
        data = event.StringInserts
        print('There were no errors found')

        print(eve_cat)
        print(eve_timegen)
        print(eve_srcnm)
        print(eve_id)
        print(eve_typ)
        print(data)
        time.sleep(10)


# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='root',
                         password='',
                         db='ptest',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)



try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `win_logs` (`Category`, `TimeGenerated`, 'SourceName', 
'EventID', 'Type') VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (eve_cat, eve_timegen, eve_srcnm, eve_id, eve_typ))

# connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
# your changes.

connection.commit()

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = "SELECT `id`, `Type` FROM `win_logs` WHERE `Category`=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
finally:
connection.close()
```

Comment: missing commit?

Comment: could it be that the loop is running infinitely without hitting connection.commit()?

Comment: @Travis I do believe this is it. I ran the code without my test database running and still received no errors. I will break the loop and see if my data inserts.

Comment: @BenjaminPharris try iterating through once and see how it goes

Comment: Iterating once was exactly what needed to happen. Now I'm encountering a nice block of mySQL errors but that is definitely progress. Will have to work through those. Thanks for helping with my silly mistake @Travis

Answer (score 2):

I can be very wrong.

But this is python.

Indentation matter.

Try just:

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `win_logs` (`Category`, `TimeGenerated`, 'SourceName`, 'EventID', 'Type') VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, (eve_cat, eve_timegen, eve_srcnm, eve_id, eve_typ))
```

I guess your `cursor` is out of `with` scope